# Cannot Get specific file from s3 using Strongloop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, amazon-s3, strongloop

I can upload, delete and get list of folders from container(s3) but not able to get specific file from amazon S3 using Strongloop.

**My code:**

```
$scope.getS3Files = function(myfolderName){ //have to get all zip files in myfolderAbc
  $http.get('api/basePath/containerABC/files/folder1/myfolderAbc=' + myfolderName).then(function (result) {
      $scope.filePath = result.data;
    }, function (err) {
      toastr.error(err.data.error.message);
    }),
  };
```

**Error:**

```
message: "Shared class "basePath" has no method handling GET /containerABC/files/folder1/myfolderAbc=myfolderName"
name: "Error"
stack: "Error: Shared class "basePath" has no method handling GET /containerABC/files/folder1/myfolderAbc=myfolderName↵    at restRemoteMethodNotFound (d:\NodeJSProjects\abc\node_modules\loopback\node_modules\strong-remoting\lib\rest-adapter.js:322:17)↵    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (d:\NodeJSProjects\abc\node_modules\loopback\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)↵    at trim_prefix (d:\NodeJSProjects\abc\node_modules\loopback\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)↵    at d:\NodeJSProjects\abc\node_modules\loopback\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7↵    at Function.process_params (d:\NodeJSProjects\abc\node_modules\loopback\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)↵    at next (d:\NodeJSProjects\abodeadmin\node_modules\loopback\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)↵    at Function.handle (d:\NodeJSProjects\abc\node_modules\loopback\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:176:3)↵    at router (d:\NodeJSProjects\abc\node_modules\loopback\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:46:12)↵    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (d:\NodeJSProjects\abc\node_modules\loopback\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)↵    at trim_prefix (d:\NodeJSProjects\abc\node_modules\loopback\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)"
status: 404
statusCode: 404
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be using **'loopback-explorer'** ! just remove that and use 'use **'loopback-component-explorer'** . You will be able to achieve your goal perfectly .