# "Shared class \"user\" has no method handling POST /1/collections"

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop, relationships

I'm trying to create relationships in StrongLoop between two models: users & collections.

No matter what i do, i just can't create a collection from the path `POST: /users/1/collection/`. Always the same error appears:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 404,
      "source": "",
      "title": "Error",
      "code": "",
      "detail": "Shared class \"user\" has no method handling POST /1/collections"
    }
  ]
}
```

So.. Searching ALOT i finally find this `github issue` showing how to "fix". And i finally did the necessary changes:

```
collection.json:

{
  "name": "collection",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "strict": false,
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    ...
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "user": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "user",
      "foreignKey": "id"
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
       "accessType": "EXECUTE",
       "principalType": "ROLE",
       "principalId": "$everyone",
       "permission": "ALLOW",
       "property": "__create__collections"
     }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

user.json:

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "strict": false,
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    ...
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "collections": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "collection",
      "foreignKey": "id"
    }
  },
  "acls": [{
   "principalType": "ROLE",
   "principalId": "$everyone",
   "permission": "ALLOW",
   "property": "count"
  },
  {
   "principalType": "ROLE",
   "principalId": "$everyone",
   "permission": "ALLOW",
   "property": "__create__collections"
  },
  {
   "principalType": "ROLE",
   "principalId": "$everyone",
   "permission": "ALLOW",
   "property": "__count__collections"
  }],
  "methods": {}
}
```

But... didn't work, i still see the same error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've tried your models with [API Explorer](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Use+API+Explorer) and I was able to use `POST: /users/1/collections/` endpoint correctly. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35643874/cannot-get-specific-file-from-s3-using-strongloop) question suggests that you might be using 'loopback-explorer' instead of 'loopback-component-explorer'. By the way, you might want to attach a link to the github issue, you are mentioning.

Comment: I'm using loopback-component-jsonapi instead. Maybe this could be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

in "remoteMethod", you should be change: `http: {path: '/{id}/collection', verb: 'post'}` to `http: {path: '/:id/collection', verb: 'post'}`